# What causes packages to appear broken

Tags: package-management

There are many answer related to fixing either specific broken packages or fixing most/all packages in a general way. This question is related to **why** and **what** cause packages to appear broken or get broken during the package handling (downloading, setting up, installing...).

What are the reasons packages break in Ubuntu and what can be done to lessen the chances of broken packages appearing in Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you mean only debian packages (`.deb` files)?

Comment: Broken as in unmet dependencies?

Comment: I mean DEB packages only (Only Ubuntu official package format) and  unmet dependencies are also part of some of the reasons a user might get the broken package dilemma but not the only one.